# How I deal with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, allocation

It's been two days I'm stuck with this problem. 
I don't know how to handle pointers, I've read some books but they just tell what they are etc but not how to implement them with structures or functions..

This is a simple example where I dynamically allocate a `char**` with `2^n` lines and `n` columns. 
How I can initialize the string putting it equal to "\0" since it's a pointer? It gives error with two nested for.. What do I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void alloc_str(char **str,int n);

int main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    char **str;

    printf("n: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    alloc_str(str,n);
    for(i=0;i<pow(2,n);i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            str[i][j] = "\0";
    return 0;
}

void alloc_str(char **str,int n){
    int i;
    str = malloc (pow(2,n) * sizeof(char *));
    if(str == NULL) exit(1);
    for(i=0;i<pow(2,n);i++){
        str[i] = malloc(n * sizeof (char));
        if(str[i] == NULL) exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It looks like there is only one problem: `"\0"` should be `'\0'`.

Comment: If all you want to do is to initialise to `\0` then you can use `calloc` instead of `malloc`

Comment: Anyway, `2^n = 1 << n`. No need to use functions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. He is using `pow` for that .

Comment: @ameyCU As I said, no need for that. Especially given that it is `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 str[i][j] = "\0";
```

This expression is assigning a string . You should use single quotes-

```
 str[i][j] = '\0';
```

And to initialize , you don't need loop, use `memset` for it , or instead use `calloc` for allocation and initialization.